# App is fails when I try set customInfoViewController to nil

Tags: objective-c, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

CustomInfoViewController property of AVPlayerViewController is nil by default.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/2868498-custominfoviewcontroller?language=objc

When I set new ViewController as custom all is fine:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 100);
    vc.title = @"TEST";
    self.playerViewController.customInfoViewController = vc; // playerViewController is AVPlayerViewController
```

But when I try to set customInfoViewController back to nil (to hide it) - it always fails:

```
self.playerViewController.customInfoViewController = nil;



*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010746ea56 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106537031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001074ae54c _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010737bccd -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 237
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107382694 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    5   AVKit                               0x000000010723997c -[AVPlayerViewController(AVPlayerViewControllerControls) setCustomInfoViewController:] + 88
```

Any suggestions how I can hide customInfoViewController?

Comment: My first thought is the line you suspect is innocent.  Can you add an exception breakpoint to be certain?

Comment: @danh I already did it. It is really failed on `customInfoViewController = nil;` You can see it by crash logs: `5   AVKit                               0x000000010723997c -[AVPlayerViewController(AVPlayerViewControllerControls) setCustomInfoViewController:] + 88`

Answer (score 0):

Settings a property to nil will not hide it!
Depends on how you presented `CustomInfoViewController`.
If you presented it using `present` function, you should call `dismiss` and set it to `nil` inside the completion block.
if you presented it by simply adding its view to AVPlayerViewController's view, you need to remove it from its superview (using `removeFromSuperview()`) and only then, set it to nil.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I didn't `present` it and didn't use `addSubview()` to set CustomInfoViewController. I just set it by `self.playerViewController.customInfoViewController = vc; // playerViewController is AVPlayerViewController`. How can I hide customInfo from top menu?

Comment: Why to hide it if you never presented it? I don't understand your question

Comment: CustomInfoViewController is not needed to `present` or `addSubview()`. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/209/ (24:35) for details how to use CustomInfoViewController.